# Ferber method advice

Tags: infant, sleep-training

My son is 9 months old and we started the Ferber method a few nights ago to hopefully eliminate the # of wake times throughout the night. The first night we started with the 3 min as our first wait time, then 5min, then 10, etc.  The second and 3rd night he slept throught the night. The 4th night he woke up at 4:30 crying. My question is: would I still treat it as the 4th night in sleep training and not go in for 12 minutes as my first wait time? Or does it re set (back to 3min) since he started sleeping throught the night? Also--if he cries and then is silent for awhile and then starts crying again does the clock start over? Just looking for the Ferber pros out there that have been around the block and can offer advice :)

Comment: Welcome to the site BSmith :) Good question you have there.

Answer (score 1):

So here's what I found with a quick search. [This link](http://baby.about.com/od/sleep/ht/How-To-Help-Baby-Sleep-Using-Ferberization.htm) says:

> If your baby wakes up in the middle of the night, start back over in the process starting with the lowest wait time from the beginning of the night.

And:

> Evaluate how the method is working for you

So judging from what you said, I would say go back to the interval you had set from that 4th night.

As for the crying and silent pattern, the clock wouldn't re-set until you go into the room to comfort the baby.